# A generic error occurred in GDI+ while creating image from Base64 string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image, base64

Here is my action method in asp.net mvc project-

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadSignatureTwo(String imageString)
{      
    byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imageString);

    Image img;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
       img = Image.FromStream(ms);
    }
    img.Save(path,ImageFormat.Jpeg); //in app_data folder, has write permission.
}
```

Sample content of imageString:

```
  /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/2wB .....
```

Why I'm getting that exception - `A generic error occurred in GDI+` ?

Comment: Are saving in appdata folder?

Comment: @Mir yes. it's in app_data direcory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(image);
using (var imageFile = new FileStream(Path.Combine(path,"test.jpeg"), FileMode.Create))
{
    imageFile.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    imageFile.Flush();
}
```